# Is it possible to have multiple answer-options showing in a Personality Quiz action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to make an interactive interface through actions-on-google, which will poll a user with 4 statements, to which they can provide an answer from a four-degree option set.

So an example statement with options looks like:

- Statement: I find myself waiting for people to call or write
- Answers to pick from: never, sometimes, rarely, always

I know that with the template that google (assistant) provides, one can have an Positive Response and a Negative Response. But if I make 3 more columns to extend the positive responses, since there are no negative responses in a poll the template will not be accepted and thus will not be uploaded as an action.

Is there any way to perform a poll showing 4 answers? (I have also tried the trivia and the personality quiz templates) there I saw an example where they had 'negative answer 1' and negative answer 2' so therefore I thought it must be possible to have just 4 correct answers to show the user. (see below examples)

Is there any other template best suited for a poll ?
Or is my current strategy valid, but I need to adjust the way I am going about the template fulfilment.

[image: Screenshot of my current template]

[image: The trivia template example]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we don't have a template for poll. The templates we provide are -

- Flashcard
- Personality Quiz 1
- Personality Quiz 2
- Trivia
- How-to guide

Check out the doc -> https://developers.google.com/assistant/templates